# How to remove extra unwanted decimals

Tags: javascript

I want to decrement `timeleft` using an interval like this:

```js
function timerStart(){

  let timeleft = 14;

  timer = setInterval(function(){

  timeleft -= 0.1;
  console.log(timeleft);
  
  }, 100)

};

timerStart();
```

The output is:

```
13.9

13.8

13.700000000000001

13.600000000000001

13.500000000000002

13.400000000000002

13.300000000000002

13.200000000000003

13.100000000000003

13.000000000000004

12.900000000000004

12.800000000000004

12.700000000000005

...
```

I don't understand why I get those extra decimals cause I simply have `timeleft -= 0.1;`.

The desired result is:

```
13.9

13.8

13.7

13.6

13.5

13.4

13.3

13.2

13.1

13.0

12.9

12.8

12.7

...
```

Why this happens and how to fix this?

Comment: Use `toFixed(1)` when logging to ensure it only has one decimal place

Comment: console.log(timeleft.toFixed(1))